# How can i fix ("too few arguments in function call")?

Tags: c++, .net

This is part of source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#define WPM(x,y,z,l)    WriteProcessMemory((HANDLE)x, (LPVOID)y, (LPCVOID)z, l, NULL)
#define WNOP(x,y,l)     for(int n=0; n<l; n++)WriteProcessMemory((HANDLE)((char*)x + n), (LPVOID)y, "\x90", 1);

bool salir = false;

void DisableACI(const HANDLE hProcess = NULL)
{
    WNOP(hProcess, 0x1000DDC4, 0x49);
    WPM(hProcess, 0x10004D20, "\xB0\x00\xC3", 3);
    WNOP(hProcess, 0x1000DDCB, 7);
    WPM(hProcess, 0x420AB0, "\xB8\x58\x10\x00\x00", 5);
    WPM(hProcess, 0x10004FF0, "\xC3", 1);
    WNOP(hProcess, 0x4AFF59, 6);
}
```

And i get this error:
IntelliSense: too **few arguments** in function call
'WriteProcessMemory' : function does not take **4** arguments.

Comment: Well yes - your `WNOP` macro calls `WriteProcessMemory` with four arguments. It has five parameters. How did you expect that to work? It's not clear to me what your macros are meant to achieve, so it's hard to tell even *which* of the parameters is missing - but I suspect it's the last one, and you just need to add `, NULL` at the end of your call.

Comment: @JonSkeet It looks like the 5th argument is [an optional output parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Edit: Nevermind, it should still be passed as `nullptr` if not desired.

Comment: [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) Takes five arguments not four. Which is *exactly* what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: @Cyber "If lpNumberOfBytesWritten is NULL, the parameter is ignored." *if* it is null, you still have to pass in null.

Comment: @Cyber: I suspect it's optional in terms of not having to provide a non-null pointer, but it's required in terms of the function call...

Comment: @Cyber It is "optional" in the sense that if it is NULL, it is ignored; but it must be there, in any case.

Comment: Please, please, please stop abusing macros like that. A function will result in the same thing and won't result in a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: @sjdowling is right. This code is an abomination. You couldn't even make it compile without asking here, let alone debug it into correctness. Don't use macros for that. Just don't.

Comment: Your macros are **horrible**

Comment: @JonSkeet The missing `NULL` is really the least of the OP's problems.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the error “too few arguments in function call”, the way you fix this is by passing more arguments to your function call.

The types of the arguments should match the arguments that the function call expects.

If what the code is doing is obscured by macros, try passing a flag to your compiler to expand said macros and compiling the resulting source, or just manually expanding them and examining the resulting source.

It is rarely a good idea to write code that uses macros like that.  Remove the macros, call the function directly.  Then examine the signature to `WriteProcessMemory`.

It is a horrible idea to put a non-trivial `for` loop in a macro.  It makes your code ridiculously hard to debug or understand.  Stop that.

If you need to do some work around a function, write a wrapper function.  In 99%+ of situations a wrapper function will be easier to read, easier to understand error messages, and won't cost you any performance if you make it `inline` and/or have the definition visible at the calling site.

So remove these two macros:

```
#define WPM(x,y,z,l)    WriteProcessMemory((HANDLE)x, (LPVOID)y, (LPCVOID)z, l, NULL)
#define WNOP(x,y,l)     for(int n=0; n<l; n++)WriteProcessMemory((HANDLE)((char*)x + n), (LPVOID)y, "\x90", 1);
```

and write some functions:

```
BOOL WPM(HANDLE x, void* y, void const* z, SIZE_T l) {
  return WriteProcessMemory(x, y, z, l, NULL);
}
BOOL WNOP(HANDLE x,void* y, SIZE_T l) {
  BOOL all_worked = TRUE;
  for(int n=0; n<l; n++) {
    all_worked = WriteProcessMemory((HANDLE)((char*)x + n), y, "\x90", 1) && all_worked;
  }
  return all_worked;
}
```

at which point the location of error becomes obvious.  You may have to do casts on your values as they don't match the types they should be, but casts should not be hidden behind macros.

Once those casts are done, the fix becomes obvious:

```
BOOL WNOP(HANDLE x,void* y, SIZE_T l) {
  BOOL all_worked = TRUE;
  for(int n=0; n<l; n++) {
    all_worked = WriteProcessMemory((HANDLE)((char*)x + n), y, "\x90", 1, NULL) && all_worked;
  }
  return all_worked;
}
```

While this compiles, it is still full of problems.  I am not familiar with `WriteProcessMemory` beyond a quick reading of its documentation and its name.  Its name indicates that you should only be calling it if you are an experienced progammer for whom "not enough arguments" is not a problem you'd ask on Stack Overflow: don't write to other processes until you understand basic C++.  The webpage indicates that your arguments are exceedingly strange, at least as far as I understand them.

The handle is supposed to be the handle to the PROCESS, and the pointer value `y` is supposed to be a value from its space.  WNOP does not seem to do anything reasonable at all.

`WNOP` also writes nothing but `'\x90'`, which seems strange.

Fixed versions of your functions:

```
// Intended to be called with `"a string"` in `string_to_write`:
template<unsigned N>
BOOL WPM(HANDLE process, void* address_in_process, char const(&string_to_write)[N]) {
  // -1 to skip the `'\0'`.
  ASSERT( string_to_write[N-1] == '\0' );
  return WriteProcessMemory(process, address_in_process, &string_to_write[0], N-1, NULL);
}
// does something!
BOOL WNOP(HANDLE process,void* address_in_process, char char_to_write, SIZE_T copies_to_write) {
  BOOL all_worked = TRUE;
  for(int n=0; n<l; n++) {
    char* write_target = reinterpret_cast<char*>(address_in_process) + n;
    all_worked = WriteProcessMemory(process, write_target, &char_to_write, 1) && all_worked;
  }
  return all_worked;
}

void DisableACI(const HANDLE hProcess)
{
  WNOP(hProcess, (void*)0x1000DDC4, '\x90', 0x49);
  WPM (hProcess, (void*)0x10004D20, "\xB0\x00\xC3");
  WNOP(hProcess, (void*)0x1000DDCB, '\x90', 7);
  WPM (hProcess, (void*)0x00420AB0, "\xB8\x58\x10\x00\x00");
  WPM (hProcess, (void*)0x10004FF0, "\xC3" );
  WNOP(hProcess, (void*)0x004AFF59, '\x90', 6);
}
```

note that taking `hProcess` with a default of `NULL` also seems like a horrid idea?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the last argument (NULL) in this:

```
WriteProcessMemory((HANDLE)((char*)x + n), (LPVOID)y, "\x90", 1);
```

Comment: WoW works, a lot of thx :)